# Почему git удалил папку?

Tags: git

Есть такие правила в гитигноре:

```
/bitrix/*
# включаем папку components, но исключаем components/bitrix
!/bitrix/components
/bitrix/components/bitrix/
```

В папке `/bitrix/components` лежит только папка `bitrix` c другими папками.

Когда делаю `git clean -df`, гит удаляет папку `/bitrix/components`.

Вопрос: почему? И как этого избежать, не убирая папку из исключения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git в принципе не версирует папки. Если отслеживаемых файлов в папке нет, то и папки для git'а нет.

Чтобы избежать удаления таких папок обычной практикой является создание в них и добавление в git пустого файла. Имя может быть любым, но классикой считается `.gitkeep`

Comment: Про папки я вкурсе, .gitkeep помог по сути, да.

Comment: То есть ответ в том, что раз он не видит в папке /bitrix/components никаких файлов, то смело её убирает, даже если она в гитигноре определена, я понял